# Is there a way to adjust Twilio "invalid content-type" debug errors?

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, twilio-php

In this case, I am using an Express.js server to handle inbound Twilio webhooks and return an `http response`

However, I am seeing Twilio errors display in the debug console. This is the error Twilio displays in their console:

```
sourceComponent "14100"
ErrorCode   "12300"
LogLevel    "ERROR"
Msg "Invalid Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 supplied"
contentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
EmailNotification   "false"
```

I looked into overriding the `Content-Type` that is returned, but Express.js [overrides this](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/8).

We're able to handle the inbound message so this doesn't seem fatal to my application, but should I be more concerned about this? Anything I should be looking into deeper?

I'm also looking into this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646394/twilio-error-12300-invalid-content-type-only-sometimes) (their app uses C#) where the answer seemed to be UTF8 encoding, but not sure if that solves the problem if Express.js overrides anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use Express to return the appropriate MIME type, as defined [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilio-understands-mime-types). Reference this repo to see the code.

[TwilioQuest Starter Template Node](https://github.com/twilio/starter-node)

```
// Return an XML response to this request
  res.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
```

Comment: hi @Alan, Ive actually tried this and Express overrides and appends the `charset=utf-8` string

Comment: That should be ok, but text/xml, not application/json.

Comment: thanks Alan, do you recommend I utf-8 encode that as well? Or fine as is?

Comment: As a follow on @Alan, I found that even setting the header["Content-Type"] with `text/xml` the charset=utf-8 was still appended and caused another validation issue with Twilio. I'm surprised that twilio isn't aware of and sensitive to Express.js particularity

Comment: You can always open an issue on the repo with steps to reproduce, https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues